# Converting string to csv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, export-to-csv

I have a piece of code in Ruby which essentially adds multiple lines into a csv through the use of
`csv_out << listX`
I have both a header that I supply in the **options and regular data.
And I am having a problem when I try to view the CSV, mainly that all the values are in one row and it looks to me that any software fails to recognize '\n' as a line separator.

Input example:

`Make, Year, Mileage\n,Ford,2019,10000\nAudi, 2000, 100000`

Output dimensions:

8x1 table

Desired dimensions:

3x3 table

Any idea of how to go around that? Either by replacing '\n' with something or using something else than csv.generate

```
csv = CSV.generate(encoding: 'UTF=8') do |csv_out|
   csv_out << headers
   data.each do |row|
      csv_out << row.values
   end
```

Comment: Please post your actual code rather than just describing it. Right now I am unclear on the issue you are experiencing because the CSV docs clearly states that the column separator defaults to comma and the row separator defaults to :auto (which includes "\r\n", "\n", and "\r")

Comment: How do you _try to view the CSV_? What tool do you use?

Comment: _"any software fails"_ – which software is that in particular? CSV isn't fully standardized, you might have to adjust `col_sep` or `row_sep`. (or set your software's import options)

Comment: At the moment when I try to copy csv variable (which is a long string) and save it as txt file, software like Excel, Numbers and Google Sheets displays it as one row in 8x1 dimensions

Comment: @ArthurEdelman maybe you copy those `\n` literally? Try `File.write("cars.csv", csv)` to eliminate copy-paste errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be the `data.each` part. Assuming that `data` holds the string you have posted, this loop is executed only once, and the string is written into a single row.

You have to loop over the indivdual pieces of `data`, for instance with

```
data.split("\n").each
```

Comment: Data object in this case is an array of Hashes

Comment: Hence, `row` is a Hash. But `<<` assumes the argument to be either of type `String` or `CSV::row`.  What do you expect when you pass a `Hash`? See [here](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.0.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-i-3C-3C).